# getEvents() returns events not in the timeframe I'm looking for

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am searching for all events within a week.

```
//from = Mon Jul 06 00:02:00 GMT+01:00 2015
//until = Fri Jul 10 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2015
var events = calendar.getEvents(from,until);
```

It's returning me this event here that it's not within that timeframe, is there anything I am missing?

```
Event 1:
Start time: Sat Jul 04 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
End Time: Mon Jul 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

Does it only look for events within dates and not date times? According to the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsstarttime-endtime

> An event will be returned if it starts during the time range, ends during the time range, or encompasses the time range. If no time zone is specified, the time values are interpreted in the context of the script's time zone, which may be different from the calendar's time zone.

Also on the example provided on the documentation, it's looking for events in a 2 hour timeframe.

As a note, both calendar and script are on the same Timezone.

Thank you!

------- Edit -------

To generate the date I get a value from a field and I generate it from there:

```
var day = aux_s.getRange(4,4);
var month = aux_s.getRange(5,4);
var year = aux_s.getRange(6,4);

var initialdate = new Date(year.getValue(), month.getValue()-1, day.getValue(), 0, 0, 0, 0)
var until = new Date(initialdate);
var from = new Date(initialdate.getTime() + (2 * 60 * 1000));
until.setDate(until.getDate()+4);
```

The values it shows when I log them are:

```
//from = Mon Jul 06 00:02:00 GMT+01:00 2015
//until = Fri Jul 10 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2015
```

However it still picks the event that ends up at 06 00:00:00 GMT+01:00.

Comment: it would be helpful to show the code that creates `from` & `until`

Comment: This _smells_ like a timezone mismatch. You've said cal & script were on the same Timezone - it would be worthwhile checking for evidence of that. As per @BryanP's comment, knowing how the event times are created would be helpful, especially as that could introduce a time zone mismatch as well.

Comment: Sorry guys, I had no internet for a few days. I've edited the question with more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I am sorry if you feel this should've been a comment but I felt sharing my code and output would be in a better understandable format here and would add value of what I am trying to show.

I don't know how you're setting your date and time but I tried this out just now:

```
function getCalEvents()
{
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('******@gmail.com');
  var from = new Date('July 6, 2015 06:00:00 AM PST');
  var until = new Date('July 9, 2015 06:00:00 PM PST');

  var events = cal.getEvents(from, until);
  Logger.log(events.length);
  Logger.log(from);
  Logger.log(until);

  for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++)
  {
    Logger.log(events[i]);
  }
}
```

The Log output I received from the above code is:

```
[15-07-09 18:47:34:162 PDT] 3.0
[15-07-09 18:47:34:163 PDT] Mon Jul 06 07:00:00 GMT-07:00 2015
[15-07-09 18:47:34:164 PDT] Thu Jul 09 19:00:00 GMT-07:00 2015
[15-07-09 18:47:34:166 PDT] CalendarEvent
[15-07-09 18:47:34:167 PDT] CalendarEvent
[15-07-09 18:47:34:167 PDT] CalendarEvent
```

I would recommend checking what date and time your script is accepting by using the `Logger`. I have tested multiple scenarios in this an App Script is returning the required results.

**EDIT:**
I never noticed the PST-PDT difference until Mogsdad pointed that out. Hence, as he suggested it only leaves one possibility of the time-zone mismatch as a possible explanation of this issue.

Comment: The 1-hour difference is explained by the two time zones being used, PST vs PDT in your case, GMT vs BST for the OP (daylight savings / summer). You could adjust your times by an hour, as you suggest, but it would be more reliable to sort out your time zones. (Yes, the OP _said_ his script & calendar were on the same time zone, but without evidence the problem can be explained by a mismatch.)

Comment: And you're right, this isn't exactly an answer per se, although you do offer some valuable advice that may help arrive at a solution. It could have been posted as a different _question_ though, and a better-written one at that!

Comment: @Mogsdad I never noticed the PDT-PST difference. Thanks for pointing that out.